# How to use a path in PHP's include function

Tags: php, codeigniter, include, include-path

hope that you're doing well, I want to use the **include** function in my PHP code to summon a part of the page, the problem is that the PHP page is in another folder so in order to bring it I have to do ../folder/page.php, here what I did:
 `include '../teacher/sidebar.php';`

But it didn't work they are showing me **Message: include(./teacher/sidebar.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**
Could anybody please help me? Thank you in advance

Here there are the paths:

**The mother page where I want to use the include function:**
C:\AppServ\www\ci\application\views\backend\grades\grades.php

**And this is the path for the desired page to be included**
C:\AppServ\www\ci\application\views\backend\teacher\sidebar.php

Comment: You will have to show your dir structure and what files are where.

Comment: Show us **full** system paths for both files, the one you are including in and the second that you want to include.

Comment: also read: [CI Loader Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html?highlight=load%20view#CI_Loader::view) as loading a view is most likely what you want?

Comment: Just paths!!! :D we don't need your ASCII graphics with the tree ;)

Comment: I put the directory path guys

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, my bad

Comment: This is the path for the home page 
 where I want to use the include C:\AppServ\www\ci\application\views\backend\grades\grades.php

Comment: And this is the path for the desired page to be included C:\AppServ\www\ci\application\views\backend\teacher\sidebar.php

Comment: `include '../../teacher/sidebar.php';` is the correct relative path in this case. And as other suggested you should edit your own question instead of adding comments.

Comment: @CustomGumball edit your question to include the paths.

Comment: Paths can be relative to your current working directory.  Which gets somewhat confusing if you are trying to call an include from inside an include. You might want to include the output of the following: `var_dump(getcwd(), get_include_path(), get_included_files());` from where you are trying to call your include.

Comment: I wrote what path you should use, try it, also use Progrock's suggestion to learn more.

Comment: `<?=$this->load->view('backend/teacher/sidebar','',true)?>` anywhere in your other view

Comment: @biesior it didn't work :'(

Comment: @Progrock could you please clarify? This complicated function is new for me

Comment: @Vickel LOL it worked! I don't know why i didn't think of it as simple as this

Comment: @Vickel please write an answer, best with explain, so it can be accepted.

Comment: @biesior I'm right now looking for a dupe, but couldn't find a good one yet... give me some more minutes... or I write an answer

Comment: Fair enough! @Vickel

Comment: @biesior I found the canonical one